# Runtime error on Cocoa / OSX environment

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm just trying to wrap a quick OpenGL setup using `Cocoa` on a `Mac OSX (snow leopard 10.6.3)` on *VirtualBox*. I'm using but a single `.cpp` file with the embedded *OBJ C*.

My (relevant) code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
   #include <unistd.h>          'usleep'
   // OpenGL
   #include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
   #include <OpenGL/gl.h>
   #include <OpenGL/glu.h>
   // Cocoa
   #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

   ... some interfaces in OBJ-C
#endif

int main() {

...

#ifdef __APPLE__

   bool run_mainloop = true;

      // the main OpenGL loop
      while(run_mainloop) {
         NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

         // Cocoa event loop
         while(1) {
            [pool release];
            pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            NSEvent *event;
            event = [NSApp
              nextEventMatchingMasK: NSAnyEventMask
              untilDate: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
              dequeue:YES
            ];

            ...

            [pool release];
         }
      }

#endif
```

The command to compile the code is the following (i'm usin *gcc*):

```
g++ -x objective-c++ -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL main.cpp -o macbin.out
```

The compilation is resulting without errors but with the warning:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:188: warning: no ‘-nextEventMatchingMasK:untilDate:dequeue:’ method found
main.cpp:188: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
main.cpp:188: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept
main.cpp:188: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.)
```

When ii try to run my binary with:

```
./macbin.out
```

i'm getting an `uncaught exception` error:

```
2014-10-13 13:05:46.362 macbin.out[476:903] -[NSApplication    nextEventMatchingMasK:untilDate:dequeue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance   0x100118190
2014-10-13 13:05:46.367 macbin.out[476:903] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-10-13 13:05:46.369 macbin.out[476:903] -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMasK:untilDate:dequeue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100118190
2014-10-13 13:05:46.372 macbin.out[476:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMasK:untilDate:dequeue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance     0x100118190'...
```

Can anyone shed some light in this? How can i set the `nextEventMatchMask` which is obviously the error? Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo

```
nextEventMatchingMasK:
```

should be:

```
nextEventMatchingMask:
```

You might be used to a different environment where something like that won't compile.  Objective-C will push a lot of considerations to runtime  However, the compiler probably should be warning you about an unknown selector?

Looks like there might be more wrong with that message:

```
- (NSEvent *)nextEventMatchingMask:(NSUInteger)mask untilDate:(NSDate *)expiration inMode:(NSString *)mode dequeue:(BOOL)flag
```

Try passing NSDefaultRunLoopMode for inMode: instead of untilDate:

```
event = [NSApp
          nextEventMatchingMask: NSAnyEventMask
          untilDate: [NSDate distantPast]
          inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
          dequeue:YES
        ];
```

Comment: thanx for the catch :) But i still the method can't be found.. wondering why

Comment: It turned out i was mixing the `inMode` and `untilDate` as well. Thanx.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, yes i'm mostly a Windows and a bit of linux coder so Obj-C is just a bit of a jungle to me :) thanx for the details